# How to redirect a http POST with urlrewritefilter

Tags: url-rewriting, http-post, http-get, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have a question about the urlrewritefilter and until now I could not find anything about it in the net.

I want to redirect a http POST in Tomcat7. Here is an example...

The call is a HTTP POST to an ULR like

```
http://localhost:8080/oldApplication/Example?a=123&b=2
```

This call also contains some content either as xml or json. The filter is configured well as it works and the urlrewrite.xml contains:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlrewrite PUBLIC "-//tuckey.org//DTD UrlRewrite 4.0//EN"
"http://www.tuckey.org/res/dtds/urlrewrite4.0.dtd">

<urlrewrite use-query-string="true">
    <rule>
        <condition type="method">POST</condition>
        <from>^(.*)$</from>
        <to type="redirect">/newApplication$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

In the access log I can see that a call to

```
http://localhost:8080/oldApplication/Example?a=123&b=2
```

gets redirected to

```
http://localhost:8080/newApplication/Example?a=123&b=2
```

Fine until now. The problem is that the rewrite changes the method, so that the new url gets called with a HTTP GET instead of a HTTP POST. I tried to add a condition on the method but got still a HTTP GET after the rewrite.

Does anybody know how to configure the rewritefilter to avoid this?

Comment: I am sorry... now i know the answer... a redirect of a http post is not possible

Comment: You could answer your own question, just to close it.

Answer (score 3):

You are using the type attribute redirect on `type="redirect"`

This attribute is equivalent to `HttpServletResponse.sendRedirect()` that actually does a new request to the destination using the `GET` method, so all parameters are lost along with the HTTP method.

The default value for this attribute if not informed is `forward` that is equivalent to `HttpServletRequest.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward()`

Forwarding will keep all request parameters and also the HTTP method.

So, in order to obtain the desired result you have to omit your type attribute or set it to `forward`.

```
<to>/newApplication$1</to>
```

or

```
<to type="forward">/newApplication$1</to>
```